# How does Grails process static files without resources plugin?

Tags: javascript, css, grails

I'm implementing Grails plugin and have big problems because Grails triggers `onChange` event before it reloads static resources. So sometimes it returns out of date version of css/js.

Pls explain me how does Grails reload static resources (css/js) (when I run application with `run-app`)? Is it possible to trigger `onChange` event after static resources are reloaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... I've spend 4-5 hours to debug it. Grails uses Tomcat to process static resources - check `org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet.serveResource` method. Tomcat caches static resources for 5 seconds. So there may be situation that Grails triggers plugin that file was changed but Tomcat will return cached value on `GET` request. I've created ticket [ticket](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-10394) and described it more precisely

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the resources plugin, you can check [his source code](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-resources/blob/master/ResourcesGrailsPlugin.groovy). I think he schedule a change and may cancel it if you change the file again.

```
def onChange = { event ->
        if (event.source instanceof FileSystemResource) {
            if (isResourceWeShouldProcess(event.source.file)) {
                log.info("Scheduling reload of resource files due to change of file $event.source.file")
                triggerReload {
                    event.application.mainContext.grailsResourceProcessor.reloadChangedFiles()
                }
            }
        } else if (handleChange(application, event, getResourceMapperArtefactHandler().TYPE, log)) {
            log.info("Scheduling reload of mappers due to change of $event.source.name")
            triggerReload {
                event.application.mainContext.grailsResourceProcessor.reloadMappers()
            }
        } else if (handleChange(application, event, getResourcesArtefactHandler().TYPE, log)) {
            log.info("Scheduling reload of modules due to change of $event.source.name")
            triggerReload {
                event.application.mainContext.grailsResourceProcessor.reloadModules()
            }
        }
    }
```